# i stuck how to create pyramid using python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pyramid of asterisks program in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911341/pyramid-of-asterisks-program-in-python)

I've written a program in C++ that displays a pyramid of asterisk (see below) and now I'd like to see how it's done in Python but it's not as easy as I'd thought it would be. :) Has anyone tried this and if so could you show me code that would help out? 2) Within those lines the number of "*" will appear as an ODD number
(1 ,3 ,5 ,7 ,9 )

this is the output

```
   *  1
 ***  3
***** 5
```

Comment: No-one's going to write your code for you. What do you have so far?

Comment: Where's the code you've used to attempt this? :-)

Comment: Wow, you even copied a similar question word for word?? You are NOT ready for a real job as a programmer. You even stole your 'working' from the answer in the other question. I sincerely hope you fail this interview.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: This may not work in Python 3.x:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May 27 2011, 21:41:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print '''   *  1
...  ***  3
... ***** 5'''
   *  1
 ***  3
***** 5
```

Comment: (+1) for even getting the misaligned asterisks to exactly match the OP's spec.

Comment: thankz, but is it have any coding to generate that sequences?

Comment: huhu..pls help me..this is my coding to pass my interview internship..

Comment: upvoted for a good answer to a bad question

Comment: @mohd izat: I'm not sitting the interview for you. If you show me with which bit you are struggling, I'll help you get past that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult..

```
>>> lower = 1
>>> higher = 19
>>> for i in xrange(lower,higher,2):
...     print ' ' * [Calculation Here] + '*' * i
... 
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
```

Comment: Given that this is for a coding interview, asking others to pass it for you should be an indicator that you're not ready for this job. I originally posted the answer because I thought it was just a fun thing.

Comment: Within those lines the number of "*" will appear as an ODD number
(1 ,3 ,5 ,7 ,9 ). can we?

Comment: i know, but i m willing to learn python language..thanks bro..

Comment: @Johnsy, I didn't realise this was for an interview, so I've modified the answer slightly.

Comment: Willing to learn is one thing. But you must LEARN. Show an example of your working so far, and then ask for help, not the answer. If you DO get the job, and they find out your skill is much less than they thought given your interview, they may come to the conclusion you cheated and fire you anyway. That means you should attempt the interview as you would attempt a real project.

Comment: @mohd izat: Have you tried counting the asterisks on each line, dividing by two and comparing the remainder with one?

Comment: def pyramid(rows=8):
    pyramid_width = rows + 2
    for asterisks in range(1, pyramid_width, 2):
        print("{0:^{1}}".format("*" * asterisks, pyramid_width))

Comment: that the example work that i had try..

Comment: That looks a lot like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911341/pyramid-of-asterisks-program-in-python/4913048#4913048

Comment: @john it's exactly the same. very unhappy with this person.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pprint

def get_vals(mVal):
   return map(lambda x: ' ' * (mVal - x - 1) + ('*' * x) + ' %i' % x, xrange(1, mVal, 2))

pprint.pprint(get_vals(12))
```