# Python 3: creating a Letter Pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a text pyramid with a height of 291 lines.   By this I mean:

```
Here is an example of a pyramid of height 6:   
 -----a-----    
----bcd----   
---efghi---  
--jklmnop--  
-qrstuvwxy-  
zabcdefghij  

Notice:   
-- each line has the same number of characters  
-- the letters a-z form the pyramid, and are re-used.
```

So far all I have is this:

```
letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#(291*2)-1
for i in range (581):
```

I really want to learn how to do this, so any help or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, rather than the answer itself :)

Comment: If you really want to learn then first try  something yourself.

Comment: There are plenty of hints on SO already; take a look at [Pyramid of asterisks program in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4911341) for example.

Comment: Thank you, I actually read that prior to posting. My real problem is how to get the dashes in there. I could do it easily if all I had to do was lines with the right letters, but I also need the correct alignment of the pyramid, with the dashes.

Comment: @user1745840 the  first answer on the linked post from  @Martijn Pieters's  comment used spaces instead of `-`, you can replace those  spaces by `-`

Answer (score 7):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
height = 6
width = height*2-1

it = cycle(letters)
for count in range(1, width+1, 2):
    print(''.join(islice(it, count)).center(width, '-'))
```

This solution uses the [***itertools***](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html) module.
The [**`cycle`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function makes an iterator that repeats our sequence of letters indefinitely, and [**`islice`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is used to take the next `count` letters from it each time (as they're spitted out character by character, we make them into one string with `''.join(...)`). So we have the next line, but without the dashes. The rest is easy: just [**`center`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) it.

---

Another very similar solution, just without *itertools*:

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
height = 6
width = height*2-1

buf = ""
def next_letters(n):
    global buf, letters
    while len(buf)<n:
        buf += letters
    ret, buf = buf[:n], buf[n:]
    return ret

for count in range(1, width+1, 2):
    print(next_letters(count).center(width, '-'))
```

The `buf` (buffer) variable will hold the next letters from the sequence. The `next_letters` function will check if there are enough letters in it and extend it as necessary, then return its first `n` letters and "remove" them.

Let's see how it works with a "debug version":

> ```
> letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
> height = 6
> width = height*2-1
>
> buf = ""
> def next_letters(n):
>     global buf, letters
>     print("Requested {} letters. Buffer is '{}'".format(n, buf))
>     while len(buf)<n:
>         buf += letters
>         print("Buffer was extended to '{}'".format(buf))
>     ret, buf = buf[:n], buf[n:]
>     print("Returned '{}'; buffer is now '{}'".format(ret, buf))
>     return ret
>
> for count in range(1, width+1, 2):
>     print(next_letters(count).center(width, '-'))
> ```
>
> Requested 1 letters. Buffer is ''
>   Buffer was extended to 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'a'; buffer is now 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   -----a-----
>   Requested 3 letters. Buffer is 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'bcd'; buffer is now 'efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   ----bcd----
>   Requested 5 letters. Buffer is 'efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'efghi'; buffer is now 'jklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   ---efghi---
>   Requested 7 letters. Buffer is 'jklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'jklmnop'; buffer is now 'qrstuvwxyz'
>   --jklmnop--
>   Requested 9 letters. Buffer is 'qrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'qrstuvwxy'; buffer is now 'z'
>   -qrstuvwxy-
>   Requested 11 letters. Buffer is 'z'
>   Buffer was extended to 'zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   Returned 'zabcdefghij'; buffer is now 'klmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>   zabcdefghij

Comment: Wow, I really do appreciate it! Could you just explain one thing? The last 2 lines don't really make sense to me. It works, I would just love to understand it. I think it is the count and join and islice parts...