# Asterisk Pyramid Not Spaced Correctly

Tags: python

Here is my code but I'm having trouble getting the pyramid to be spaced correctly like a pyramid and also to only have odd number of asterisks per line.
Output when you enter 7 for the base should be

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

This is my code:

```
base = int(input( 'enter an odd number for the base : ' ) )
for i in range( 0, base ):
    print '*' * i
```

Comment: Wow, this is a blast from the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911341/pyramid-of-asterisks-program-in-python/4911427#4911427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`str.center()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.center):

```
for i in range(1, base + 1, 2):
    print ('*' * i).center(base)
```

but do use a step size of 2, and adjust your range. The first line starts with 1 star always, and `range()` doesn't include the last value.

For `7`, that means you want to print 1, 3, 5 and 7 stars, incrementing by 2 each iteration.

Comment: If i now wanted to do the same thing with odd numbers and 2 for each iteration but make a diamond shape, how do i do that? i'm assuming you would have to have the triangle mirror itself but i don't know how to do that

Comment: Use *two* loops; the second would use negative step to range down. The first loop can go from `range(1, base, 2)` and the second would go `range(base, 0, -2)`.

Comment: actually i just tried that before i saw your comment but am having trouble getting rid of the base showing up twice

Comment: @user3317056: that's why you run the *first* range with `range(1, base, 2)`, *not* `base + 1`, so that it is not included.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code:

1. since you're using `print '...'` instead of function `print`, you may be in python2, where `raw_input` is needed instead of `input`;
2. `range(1, base+1, 2)` is needed instead, for your sample output.

Demo:

```
In [6]: base = int(raw_input( 'enter an odd number for the base : ' ) )
   ...: for i in range(1, base+1, 2):
   ...:     print ('*' * i).center(base)

enter an odd number for the base : 7
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
```