# inverted pyramid of asterisk using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

```
     ************
      **********
       ********
        ******
         ****
          **
```

code for the above:

```
j=0
k=12
for i in range(6):
    print(' '*(j),end=' ')
    print('*'*k,end=' ')
    j+=1
    k-=2
    print()
```

But I need to print the above pyramid using recursion and make sure both the spaces and asterisks are aligned as shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyramid of asterisks program in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911341/pyramid-of-asterisks-program-in-python)

Comment: @ShoaibK.I  need to solve it specifically by recursion and not loops

Comment: Ok, so what recursive solution have you tried? Do you understand the concept of recursion? What is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recursive function prints the same shape as your example :

```
width = 12

def printRow(i):
    print(' ' * i, end=' ')
    print('*' * (width - i * 2), end=' ')
    print()
    if (i < width // 2): printRow(i+1)

printRow(0)
```

Comment: can you please explain the second last line, if(i<width//2): printRow(i+1)

Comment: The number of rows is half the number of columns (`width // 2`), so the recursive calls must stop once `i` reaches that value